# Best weapons for warriors who are extremely strong?

Tags: warfare, weapons, military

The ruling caste of my empire consists of the descendants of gods. Although they are comparatively small in number, they play an important role in the military. They are extremely strong compared to mortals. What would be the best weapons for such warriors?

The technology is roughly comparable to 15th century europe, including early guns and cannons

Comment: I'm going to vote this as a duplicate even though it includes ranged weapons (see [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/53033/40609)).  Note that firearms negate strength other than the ability to lift a howitzer where others cannot.  However, in the 15th century you were dealing with one-shot guns, which would be almost useless and force you back to the indicated duplicate.

Comment: I used the search option and did not find a similar question ._.

Comment: It happens.  [Here's the search I used.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aqueston+best+weapon+strong)

Comment: Could you perhaps quantify what you mean by "extremely strong"? Today's strongest athletes would've been considered extremely strong in the drug free 15 century Europe and they are not really good fighters. You absolutely have to name numbers here because it could mean anything right now. How strong and strong at what? Humans are strong e.g. at deadlifting weight from the ground (biggest muscles in our body), but extremely weak with their arms stretched far away from their body (which might help with weapons)

Comment: The average descendant can lift around 800-900 kg.

Comment: @Andech Just for comparison, that's about as strong as a Gorilla. Perhaps that information helps you come up with your own ideas (because those are usually the best). You can of course reality check them here then. Btw, not saying that this question cannot be answered here, just saying, from experience, when building a world, introducing other people's ideas based - especially if they have a superior knowledge about military tactics, weaponry, history, biomechanics and so on that you can't really copy can lead to trouble down the road

Comment: @JBH i'm gonna go out on a limb here and suggest that one-shot guns are not useless; discharging a handcannon full of grapeshot into a formation of infantry at close range would be _brutal_. Also, regular cannon and siege crossbows are also single shot and slow to reload, but remained useful.

Comment: That said, I feel like if you were mostly interested in melee stuff, the linked question has plenty of good answers and this one could be closed. If you were interested in guns, you should probably overhaul the question or post a new one instead. I'll hold off V-ingTC for now.

Comment: @StarfishPrime my point was that it was something you could only do once without reloading, limiting the effectiveness.  I agree that if the OP wants to focus only on guns, that would remove duplicate status.  I'd retract my VTC in that case.

Comment: @JBH I've just remembered about [organ guns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribauldequin). All together now, "_did I fire six cannons, or did I fire five? in all that excitement I kinda lost track myself..._"

Comment: @StarfishPrime oh, that is *too cool!*  Especially with the Dirty Harry allusion.  Andech, wanna refocus your question on just firearms of the period?  I think StarfishPrime's feeling lucky!

Comment: Is it allowed to change a question like that? I would be interested, especially because the other two questions don't deal with early gunpowder.

Comment: An important consideration is that in combat those demigods would likely seek out and duel their own kind. So those weapons should, above all, be sturdy.

Comment: @Andech now this one has been closed, it seems reasonable to just create a new and more specific one. Alas, I am off to bed, but if you make it I'll look in tomorrow and throw together an answer if my idea hasn't already been used ;-)