Why would swords be the ideal weapon for superhumans?
Basically, my magic setting has superhuman mages. They are supernaturally stronger, faster, and more durable beyond what their human bodies are naturally capable off. These mages are wandering martial artists, searching to kill each other so they can establish who's the best among them.
They forge handheld weapons able to fully utilize their superhuman traits. These weapons are nearly the same as ours with the exception of being supernaturally durable to not shatter when swung on their adversaries.
For reasons, I want my mages to predominantly wield swords when fighting.
From some quick research, swords were historically treated more as ceremonial symbols and were not effective killers compared to halberds or spears which offered greater reach and variability.
Regardless of this, how would I justify swords being the most optimal weapon for them?
An ideal answer will provide a reason with the best internal consistency for why swords would be the best weapons for these mages given the constraints of the magic system as listed.

We are not a brainstorming site. Instead of asking us to do your worldbuilding for you, instead make up any reason why swords are used over other weapons, and ask us for help resolving any specific issue that happens to come up as you build your own world. Questions with many valid a answers have never been permitted on this site. There are many ways to justify this, including not explaining anything and just saying, "in my world they use swords". I suspect that avoiding an info dump about why will improve the quality of any story you actually write.

Also possible duplicate question. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22124/what-would-be-the-ideal-melee-weapon-for-someone-with-superhuman-strength

Question: What is the Tech level of your world?

This is straight up Narrative Necessity. In this case, more the second definition rather than the first. You've made a fundamental decision about your story --- swords! Now that the decision is made, you need "something" that will justify your choice. This "something" is narrative necessity itself. It's not a function of the world itself so much as an authorial choice. As such, this question is off topic for WB.SE. VTC.

Maybe the material of the swords are found in a certain shape or can only be smelted to a certain shape

What is the problem here? What is 'optimal' for you? Why sword works but dagger and other blades won't work? You tell us the problem, and we can answer.

As it's an opinion question I'll only post this as a comment. You might be better served by the culture between mages. It is like asking the question who is best at martial arts. If we ignore MMA, the competitions are between people of similar martial arts. Being the best mage means being the best as a mage, and not the best with a gun. Swords can be a cultural thing from long ago, and you do not violate the rules for fear of a manhunt on you specifically.

For the record a metric to compare answers does nothing to reduce the number of valid answers and therefor fails to address the issues of this question or make it eligible for reopening.

Conductivity:
The superhuman abilities attach to the hero's body, and closely. What really makes the swords special is the metal is able to conduct the field of the magic to include the sword (although smaller weapons, such as knives would work as well). They must be a continuous piece of metal. The sword is simply an ordinary weapon of a slightly odd alloy for anyone who ISN'T a superhero.
There are clear limits on exactly how far the field can be extended, and this makes the sword's maximum size and length rigidly fixed. Where two fields come in contact, they tend to oppose, so an attacker must focus their attack to a very small area (blade/point). These fields are functionally like armor, and an opposing field (rather than the actual weapon) is the most efficient way to penetrate the protective effect of an opponent's field.
This means that armor isn't significantly better protection against a field than the field itself. Blunt weapons spread the impact out too much. Martial artists will be able to punch and throw each other around spectacularly before punches and kicks become lethal.
You can tweak the specifics to favor whatever kind of sword you like, and there will always be exceptions that are useful (so opponents can still have the occasional exotic weapon for flavor). But a sword will meet all the requirements for maximum lethality.



Swords are generally going to be inferior to most other weapons. I'd suggest making the swords unique, they use swords not because they are optimal but because they are better than anything else available.
Maybe they're made from a unique supernatural ore, anything that touches it over time is corroded or destroyed so nothing can be bonded to it. So the sword is basically one forged piece of metal with no wraps, no handles, it cannot be attached to a shaft, a sword is basically your best option for such an ore.
Maybe the swords were made by an ancient long gone civilisation, nobody else can replicate the technology held by the ancients so no other weapons can be made with similar properties. They could hold powerful properties making them far superior to anything else, maybe normal humans are unable to wield these swords so only superhumans use them.

It sounds as if your "wandering superhuman mages" are individual fighters without the support of hundreds (or thousands) of other fighters, and without the support of an army train.

Either a spear or halberd has a decent length, then it becomes awkward to carry and hard to use against an individual foe at close quarters, or it is short, then it lacks the reach of a proper polearm. (Think of an iklwa vs. a pike as two extremes.)
You talk about shatterproof weapons. If the metal becomes shatterproof through superhuman workmanship, does that improve the wooden parts? Or would we be talking about a steel spearhead on a steel shaft?
If your superhumans have superhuman blades, but no superhuman armor, then the usual reasons for the use of the mace or war hammer instead of a sword disappear.

So if a weapon less than 1 or 1.5 metres in length makes sense for being practical to carry, should it be 1/3 blade and 2/3 shaft (an all-metal iklwa) or more than 2/3 blade and less than 1/3 shaft (what was later called a hand-and-a-half sword)? Especially if "cost" in the traditional sense is no category?
